# has anyone made an xsl file to generate HTML like, Jmeter Dashboard report from XML

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-maven-plugin, jmeter-3.2

I want to group the results in HTML Report by their threadName, which is available in CSV, but not displayed in the Dashboard Report, Other option I saw to get what I want was using an XML file and customising the XSL file to obtain the output, But, I also want to have those graphs available from Dashboard Report!
Has anyone else faced this and solved it??

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to generate HTML report from *.jtl in XML format, but it could be difficult. JTL files in XML format could be many times very big (~hundreds of MB) and you can also have problem to process such a big file with XSLT script. Another problem could be get the graphs in this report.
I suggest you use other options.

1. Use [SmartMeter's](https://www.smartmeter.io/) [Report Generator](https://www.smartmeter.io/blog/smartmeter-load-test-report). You can use it form [GUI](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-test-report) or from [command line](https://www.smartmeter.io/documentation#toc-reports)
2. Use [Blazemeter's Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) -  this option is very simple and easy, but could be more expensive

Comment: Thanks, I'm editing the JMeter report source for meeting my needs because my change is little and I need to group them by thread name.